# MaxLength + Asp.net Web API - Errors out

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I have this property inside my PriceDM class.

```
 [MaxLength(8)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }


   public void AddPrice([FromBody]PriceDM vm)
        {
}
```

I keep getting this error though

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to cast
>   object of type 'System.Decimal' to type
>   'System.Array'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidCastException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value)\r\n   at
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext)\r\n   at
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.Validators.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, Object container)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ShallowValidate(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.Validate(Object
>   model, Type type, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
>   HttpActionContext actionContext, String keyPrefix)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(Object
>   model)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass36`1.<>c__DisplayClass38.<Then>b__35()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass49.<ToAsyncVoidTask>b__48()\r\n
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Can I not use MaxLength with a decimal?

Comment: This was a good question. If your on this page you need more caffeine!

Answer (score 5):

if you look at [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute.aspx) you will see the follow description for the MaxLenght attribute.

> Specifies the maximum length of array or string data allowed in a
>   property.

I would try [Range attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx).